# Return Object to Pool in separate Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a loop which polls for borrowing Objects from a GenericObjectPool. Pool itself is of size 1. Code below -

```
final CompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(getExecutorServices());               
int counter = 0;

    for (Iterator iter = AList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

                borrowed = this.getPool().borrowObject();

                if (borrowed == null) {
                    throw new Exception("not set");
                } else {        
                    completionService.submit(borrowed,borrowed);
                    counter ++;
                }   
    }
```

Since pool is of size 1, after 1st borrow, it is exhausted and blocked. 
To return Objects back to pool, I think to run a separate Thread as below -

```
new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

            borrowed = completionService.take().get();
            status = borrowed.getStatus();

            getPool().returnObject(borrowed);
                        counter --;

            if (status = 1) {
                getExecutorServices().shutdownNow();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

This is a blocking call to CompletionService for acting on completion of each Thread and releasing it for making it available for borrow.

But this design has shortcomings like counter of parent can not be read from Runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a CallableDecorator to return value form Runnable to monitor Thread and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The counter is not thread-safe. Use an AtomicInteger and make it available to both the runnable and the first code block.

Comment: In first code code block , borrowed Object is submitted repeatedly. That should be fine ?

Comment: the completionService.submit(borrowed,borrowed) is from another answer to another question, I believe. You need that because you submit a runnable and want to have the same kind of runnable a result, so you can resubmit it later. Normally CS is meant for eecuting callables that return a result, but you can use it for runnables, too. Like in this example.